# Reading the response in case of exception in Exception Filter

Tags: nestjs

Here is the overall scenario.

1. We have exception filter applied on Module Level.
2. We have to call some 3rd Party REST for some data.
3. The rest call to 3rd party is failing with 400 and have some response data.
4. We have to return this to our caller.

So, in a very simple way, there are 3 sections:

1. A is calling B
2. B is calling C and C is failing having Response Body like https://run.mocky.io/v3/a3b8da60-f2a4-4658-a601-e044a151fc7b

So, if we look at the response it is something like:

```
------------ (X) --------------
HTTP RESPONSE STATUS: 400
RESPONSE BODY:
{
  status: 400,
  code: 'BAD_REQUEST',
  message: 'Message'
}
```

I need to READ this response body and send this back to A.

Here is a detailed explanation.

**app.module.ts**

```
@Module({
 .....
 providers: [
    ConvertErrorStatusToCode,
    {
      provide: 'APP_FILTER',
      useClass: HttpExceptionFilter,
    }
 ],
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule{}
```

**product.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  controllers: [<Controllers>],
  providers: [ProductService],
  imports: [HttpModule]
})
export class ProductModule {}
```

**product.service.ts**

```
 @Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
 export class ProductService {
      constructor(<HTTPSERVICE INJECTED>) {}
      async somethirdpartycall(): Promise<Partial<MyDto>> {
         // here using httpservice i call the URL pasted and 
      }
 }
```

**http-exception.filter.ts**

```
@Catch()
export class HttpExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
      
      catch(exception: any, host: ArgumentsHost) {
        const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
        const request: Request = ctx.getRequest<Request>();
        const response: Response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
        // how to read the response of the request that failed
        // at (X)
      }
}
```

I am trying to get the hold of RESPONSE BODY but unable to do so. So:

1. How to read that response body in Exception Filter
2. Is this a good approach to do this way, or we should follow some other way

Answer (score 1):

you can get the response from the exception object.
`const originalResponseBody = exception.response`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking into interceptors in official documentation

https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors#exception-mapping

Particularly `Exception mapping` which seems to be a good case for you issue (transforming error message)